# Xamarin.Android Adyen Integration & Bindings Library .aar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, aar, adyen

Hello colleagues developers,

I'm currently developing a Xamarin Form app that requires the integration of a Payment Service Provider. My company requires that I use **Adyen** as the PSP.

Adyen itself doesn't provide any information on Xamarin integration. Information exist for Android and IOS but can't find anything for Xamarin forms / Xamarin.Android.

I've created a Bindings Library (android).
I've added the.aar file provided by Adyen into it.
Then I built it with the LibraryProjectZip property but after adding the reference to my Xamarin.android project, I can't use any methods that should be in it...

I've tried this process with another .aar and everything went fine...

Does any of you have already integrated Adyen in a Xamarin form / Xamarin.android app ?

Thanks in advance,

Noste

Comment: In my guide: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb I go over a few reasons why things might not "Generate". Since there are too many, I can only point you in the right direction. Most of this has now been put on the official documentation from my gist: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/

Comment: I'll try to troubleshoot it that way, thanks for your help !